# Can we start using jetpack compose in app?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am developing an application I want to know can we use jetpack compose in current project.. is it completely stable?

Comment: No I am asking about jetpack is still in beta so can we start using in our projects? Is it save to use before stable release

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I don't know if you heard it, but compose is going stable in July. With June almost to an end, nothing will dramatically change, so YES, you can start using it in your apps. It is going stable next month which means that it is ALMOST production ready. When a toolkit goes beta, it means that most of the APIs and packages are feature complete, and are just being polished. So you do not have to fear any major refactoring when the 1.0 comes out.

Best of luck